# How to Load Items into an Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/Ls0ex5t0/) let me know how I can load items into the `ul` list as an endless list. as you can see I have this list as following code but I need to add items again and again at the end of each time list.

```
var item = $(".thumbnail").width();
var paddT = $(".thumbnail").css('margin-left');
item = item + 20;
$(".leftslide").on("click", function () {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
        left: '-=' + item + 'px'
    }, 300);
});
$(".rightslide").on("click", function () {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
        left: '+=' + item + 'px'
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: So you want circular slider or need to get new data?

Comment: hi anwerjunaid , thanks for reply yes I need circular slider with same existing data

Comment: ok! let me see your jsfiddle codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by appending the first item/prepending the last item on leftslide/rightslide, and subsequently removing it, when the animation has completed. Then reset the position.

```
var item = $(".thumbnail").width();
var paddT = $(".thumbnail").css('margin-left');
item = item + 20;
$(".leftslide").on("click", function () {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
        left: '-=' + item + 'px'
    }, 300, function() {
        $(".list-inline").append('<li>' + $('li').first().html() + '</li>');
        $('li').first().remove();
        $(".list-inline").css({left: '+=' + item + 'px'});
    });
});
$(".rightslide").on("click", function () {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
        left: '+=' + item + 'px'
    }, 300, function() {
        $(".list-inline").prepend('<li>' + $('li').last().html() + '</li>');
        $('li').last().remove();
        $(".list-inline").css({left: '-=' + item + 'px'});
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls0ex5t0/3/

Answer (score 2):

This is not a circular slider par se , but works same way.

```
            var item = $(".thumbnail").width();
            var paddT = $(".thumbnail").css('margin-left');
            var current= 0;
            var total= $(".list-inline li").length;
            item = item + 20;
            $(".leftslide").on("click", function () {
                    current++;
                    if(current>=total){
            //                      $(".list-inline").animate({
            //                              left: '0px'
            //                      }, 300);
            //              current=0;
                            return;
                    }
                    $(".list-inline").animate({
                            left: '-=' + item + 'px'
                    }, 300);

            });
            $(".rightslide").on("click", function () {
                    current--;
                    if(current<=0){
            //                      $(".list-inline").animate({
            //                              left: '0px'
            //                      }, 300);
            //              current=0;
                            return;
                    }
                    $(".list-inline").animate({
                            left: '+=' + item + 'px'
                    }, 300);
            });
```

I have commented the portion where it goes back! Try this.

Comment: Great thanks anserjunaid, This is also  good solution but is there any way to stop sliding as soon as last item shows up in the front? I mean right now as you can see the last item slides to the left even when there is no more item at right hand (with empty space) can we stop that? once again thanks